# NSURLErrorDomain (SSL Error) on LTE, but not on Wifi

Tags: ios, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have an app I was about to submit to the App Store, when I noticed that on production the app wasn't working when on LTE (I was doing most of my development/testing on Wifi).

Both LTE and Wifi work on my dev server (different cert). Wifi works on my production server — however, when I try to use the app on LTE through my Testflight build, I get this error:

2017-09-26 22:44:59.310820-0400 Spott[8807:931969] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c1449600 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://getspott.com/user/login.xml, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://getspott.com/user/login.xml, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://getspott.com/user/login.xml, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://getspott.com/user/login.xml, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

Has anyone run into this issue before where one mode of connection works and the other doesn't?

I'm on iOS 11. Using an older version of AFNetworking (1.3.4). I'm porting an app that was last used on iOS 7. I was thinking about totally rewriting the web client, but it is working on dev.

Comment: I believe I tracked this down to an IPv6 issue. More to come. https://blogs.akamai.com/2016/06/preparing-for-ipv6-only-mobile-networks-why-and-how.html

Comment: The fix was supporting IPv6 on my web server. Interesting the Verizon in my area is IPv4, while ATT and T-Mobile are IPv6.

Comment: Similar problem: iOS 12.1, Swift 4,2 and last version of Alamofire, SSL enabled on all servers with TLS 1.2. It only occurs on a singular IPS.